# Sequelize.js: Query for not in array ($ne for items in array)

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am looking to pull items from a postgres data base with Sequelize, but only return items that have an id that does not equal any items in a given array.

In the [Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/2.0/docs/querying/), there are operators `$ne` for `not equal` and `$in` for returning items that have properties with values that match the given array, but it doesn't look like there is an operator for something that combines those two.

For example, if I were to have items in my database with ids `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, and I wanted to filter those by comparing to another array (ie `[2,3,4]`), so that it would return items `[1, 5, 6]`. In my example i also randomize the return order and limit, but that can be disregarded.

```
function quizQuestions(req, res) {
  const query = {
    limit: 10,
    order: [ [sequelize.fn('RANDOM')] ],
    where: {
      id: { $ne: [1, 2, 3] } // This does not work
    }
  };

  Question.findAll(query)
  .then(results => res.status(200).json(map(results, r => r.dataValues)))
  .catch(err => res.status(500).json(err));
}
```

Edit: With @piotrbienias answer, my query looks like this:

```
  const query = {
    limit: 10,
    order: [ [sequelize.fn('RANDOM')] ],
    where: {
      id: { $notIn: [1, 2, 3] }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There exists [**`$notIn`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database), you must have missed it. Exemplary query with `$notIn` generates

```sql
SELECT "id", "name"
FROM "categories" AS "Category"
WHERE "Category"."id" NOT IN (1, 2);
```

**EDIT**

The documentation you refer to is for `2.0` version of Sequelize, you should update to `3.0`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I actually didn't notice I was reading the 2.0 docs when I posted. I am using sequelize 3.30.2, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 57):

using

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op
where: {
      id: {[Op.notIn]:[1, 2, 3]}
}
```

See [operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators):

> Sequelize exposes symbol operators that can be used for to create more complex comparisons