# Sequelize query: How to find column, "where:" the column value is not equal to any value in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables, user and Matches. I am making a query to findAll values in a column, in the Matches table. Then I want to query the user table and findAll rows that don't have an id equal to any value queried from the match table.

```
db.Matches.findAll({
    where: { WLID: { $ne: currentUser } },

    attributes: ['GLID']


}).then(function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
    // console.log(data);

    var GLIDsToPass = [];

    data.forEach((dataItem) => {

        GLIDsToPass.push(dataItem);

        console.log(dataItem.get({
            plain: true
        }));
    });

});

db.user.findAll({

    where: {
        id: {
            $ne: req.user.id
        }
    },
    where: {
        id: {
            $ne: "WHAT DO I PUT HERE in order to check if every value in GLIDsToPass array is not equal..."
        }
    },...
```

I have the values from the Matches table stored in an array. how can I:

```
 where: {
    id: {
        $ne: "any value in GLIDsToPass array"
    }
},
```

Comment: I know this is an old question but the answer above didn't work for me and if you are using postgres,using a json array formatted like [1,2,3],will cause the following syntax error : "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: malformed array literal"
and in order to fix that you need to reformat your array to look like this {1,2,3}.However using the operator "any" didn't work for me but the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125925/sequelize-js-query-for-not-in-array-ne-for-items-in-array) worked perfectly with json array([1,2,3]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the `$notLike` operator?

Perhaps:

`$notLike: { $any: ['cat', 'hat']}`

Take a look here under operators! http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html

Yours might look something like:

```
where: {
    id: {
        $notLike: { $any: GLIDs }
    }
},
```

Comment: You're correct - that will work. I just ran into another problem!! my variable, array... looks like this: [ { GLID: '1' }, { GLID: '2' }, { GLID: '3' } ]

How can I make it look like this: [ '1', '2' , '3'  ]

Comment: Wicked! Errm, can you do something like...

`const values = GLIDs.map(object => object.GLID)`?

@Mike

Comment: where are you suggesting I place that? I guess I'm not sure what that syntax does @Harkat

Comment: You would use that to flatten the values you pass to the selector.

Comment: The map function returns a new array from the array you choose to loop over. Basically what it looks like is this:

Your original array is: `const GLIDs = [ { GLID: '1' }, { GLID: '2' }, { GLID: '3' } ]`

You need to just return the GLID value of the objects so we [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) them: `const disallowedIds = GLIDs.map(function(glidObj) { return glidObj.GLID })`

returns `['1', '2', '3']`

Comment: gotcha!! okay. that flattens it but the query didn't work. I tried $ne and $notLike